# Free Marker template - FTL is giving test error for new line

Tags: junit, freemarker

I have below footer.ftl file as below,

```
3<#t>
~<#t>
<#-- Record -->
${incrementDate}<#t>
~<#t>
<#-- redeemRecords -->
0<#t>
~
```

and my test case ExtractFile.txt contains below record.

```
3~08DEC2018~0~
```

when doing assert on extractFile.txt and record created by footer.ftl i am getting below error as /n is getting added in extractFile.txt but not in footer.ftl

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Invalid extract file content
Expected: "3~08DEC2018~0~\n"
but: was "3~08DEC2018~0~"
```

Here \n is missing.
When running on unix i am getting above error.
when running locally it appends \r\n. \r seems to be because of env difference though so we can ignore it.
Any help on this please.

Comment: Do you have a line break at the end of that template, or not? If there is, FreeMarker should print it as is (without converting between \n and \r\n).

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: this is resolved. My bad. Expected file had new line but hooter.flt did not. Hence the issue.